# Import multiple text files in SAS and skip the firstline (header) in each file

Tags: sas

For example I have test1.txt like this,

```
One   Two   Three
1   2   3
4   5   6
```

Test2.txt like this,

```
One   Two   Three
7   8   9
10   11   12
```

Test3.txt like this,

```
One   Two   Three
13   14   15
16   17   18
```

What's the best way to import them into a table in sas and create something like this,

```
One   Two   Three
1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9
10   11   12
13   14   15
16   17   18
```

Here is my original code,

```
data want;
   infile "text*.txt" delimiter="   " firstobs=2;
   input One Two Three;
run;
```

Only the header line in the first file is skipped by the firstobs statement. I can accomplish that by writing repeating codes but that's obviously not good. I've also tried the variable EOV to detect the starting of a file, but I can't make it work. What's the best way to do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: EOV infile statement option to detect the start of each new file in the concatenation.

Comment: I honestly have tried that but with a do while loop I still can't make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the EOV option on the INFILE statement. Here is one way.

```
data want;
  infile "text*.txt" dsd dlm='09'X truncover eov=eov firstobs=2;
  input @;
  if eov then input;
  input One Two Three;
  eov=0;
run;
```

Use the `FIRSTOBS=2` infile option to skip the header on the first file and then use the conditional input to skip the header for the others. You need to make sure the EOV flag gets properly set by pre-reading the line before testing `EOV` flag. You need to reset the EOV flag at the bottom of the data step.

Comment: Thank you for your help. When I run the code it still tries to read in the second file's header and misses its second row. Then succeed in skipping the third file's header and misses its last row....There must be some logical mistakes going on. I'm trying to fix it but not yet succeed.

Comment: That's what I get for posting untested code.  Try the corrected version.

Comment: Thank you! This works and the explanation makes complete sense!